Euclidean Geometry for Math Olympiads Problem 1.21
I'm confused on this solution to a problem in the Euclidean Geometry in Math Olympiads by Evan Chen. Here is the problem and the solution.
Problem 1.21.

Prove that, in fact, $A$ is the orthocenter of triangle $HBC$.
In this case, we are okay, but the dangers are clear. For example, when triangle $ABC$ was acute, we proved that $B$, $H$, $F$, $D$ were concyclic by noticing that the opposite angles satisfied $\angle BDH + \angle HFB = 180^\circ$. Here, however, we instead have to use the fact that $\angle BDH = \angle BFH$; in other words, for the same problem we have to use different parts of Theorem 1.9 (cyclic quadrilateral theorems).


What I tried:
The non acute version is $ABC$ and the altitudes are the same points as in $HBC$, so shouldn't the orthic triangle still be the same and therefore the cyclic quadrilaterals be the same and therefore you find it in the same way?
I am really confused and they introduce directed angles after to counter this "problem" which I'm still yet to even know what it is.

Which two of the line segments $EC$, $FB$ and $DH$ are assumed to be altitudes?

Just swap $A$ and $H$

Ah yes, I think I remember this one. Here, he motivates directed angles iirc

I suggest you compare the proofs of both cases word-by-word, see f you can find something strange

omg yeah, in the original diagram A and H are swapped. I totally forgot. But I'm still a bit confused, I'm assuming EC, FB and DH to be the altitudes and therefore EFD is the orthic triangle. Everything seems to be the same except A and H are swapped

but I still don't get why even wrote this: "in other words, for the same problem we have to use different parts of
Theorem 1.9. We should not need to worry about solving the same problem twice!
How do we handle this? The solution is to use directed angles mod 180◦. Such angles
will be denoted with {directed angle symbol}
Here is how it works. First, we consider ABC to be positive if the vertices A, B, C
appear in clockwise order, and negative otherwise. In particular, ABC = CBA; they
are negatives."

why do we need directed angles for (it'll probably explain later, but why does he say "to handle this", what is the issue that directed angles are needed?)

@NotYou see my last comment

The reason why this problem would be worrying for most geometers would be that usually, they work by making a diagram (which may itself have a few flaws and look different when drawn to scale) and then chasing angles/cyclic quadrilaterals, or using other techniques to prove the necessary result. The dependance on the diagram here is worrying, after all, it would be annoying to have to take many different cases for acute/obtuse angles, which length is longer, etc.
Evan emphasizes this with the example of the Miquel point configuration, I think. In any case, problems involving many different configurations exist, and the more complex the problem, the more time-consuming it would be to handle the many cases.
Taking this example, one can show that four points are concyclic using directed angles which neatly finishes the proof.
The directed angle variant of Theorem $1.9$ is as follows:
Points $A, B, C,$ and $D$ lie on a circle if and only if $\measuredangle ABC=\measuredangle ACD$.
The proof is now a one-liner as both angles are equal to $90$ degrees, which is considered the same as $-90$.
I hope this answer helps, but highly doubt I can do better than Evan in motivating directed angles.
